# Cannot find getter for field

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kapt

I am trying to build an Android app project with two modules, one of them containing Kotlin code. I am getting the following error when building, and I don't know how to fix it.

The warnings and the error (in bold):

```
w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper' less than -source '1.8'

**e: C:\android_workspace\anapp_android\VideoApp\core\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\co\acompany\videoapp\db\model\DbChannelDetails.java:12: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private java.lang.String id;
                             ^**

w: C:\android_workspace\anapp_android\VideoApp\core\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\co\acompany\anapp\db\CompanyDatabase.java:7: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class CompanyDatabase extends android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^
:core:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorAllguitarnetworkProDebug
```

and here's the related class file:

C:\android_workspace\anapp_android\VideoApp\core\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\co\acompany\videoapp\db\model\DbChannelDetails.java:

```
package co.acompany.videoapp.db.model;

import java.lang.System;

@android.arch.persistence.room.Entity(tableName = "channel_details")
@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 9}, bv = {1, 0, 2}, k = 1, d1 = 
{"\u0000$\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0005\n\u0002\u0010\t\n\u0002\b\b\b\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0007\b\u0016\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002B\u000f\b\u0016\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0005R\u001e\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u00078\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\b\u0010\t\"\u0004\b\n\u0010\u000bR\u001e\u0010\f\u001a\u00020\r8\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u000e\u0010\u000f\"\u0004\b\u0010\u0010\u0011R\u001e\u0010\u0012\u001a\u00020\u00078\u0006@\u0006X\u0087\u000e\u00a2\u0006\u000e\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0013\u0010\t\"\u0004\b\u0014\u0010\u000b\u00a8\u0006\u0015"}, d2 = {"Lco/acompany/videoapp/db/model/DbChannelDetails;", "", "()V", "details", "Lco/acompany/videoapp/api/model/ChannelDetails;", "(Lco/acompany/videoapp/api/model/ChannelDetails;)V", "id", "", "getId", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "setId", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "rowId", "", "getRowId", "()J", "setRowId", "(J)V", "title", "getTitle", "setTitle", "core_debug"})
public final class DbChannelDetails {
@android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long rowId;
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
@android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo()
private java.lang.String id;
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
@android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo()
private java.lang.String title;

public final long getRowId() {
    return 0L;
}

public final void setRowId(long p0) {
}

@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
public final java.lang.String getId() {
    return null;
}

public final void setId(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
java.lang.String p0) {
}

@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
public final java.lang.String getTitle() {
    return null;
}

public final void setTitle(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
java.lang.String p0) {
}

public DbChannelDetails() {
    super();
}

public DbChannelDetails(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
co.acompany.videoapp.api.model.ChannelDetails details) {
    super();
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, to solve this I changed the visibility that private to public. Although I think that field should be private.

Answer (score -1):

Try change the visibility of your `@PrimaryKey` field to `protected`.

```
@android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
protected long rowId;
```